# Replacing an indexed term

Tags: replacement, summation, algebraic-manipulation

Consider the expression:

```
s[i_, n_] := Sum[(e[c[j]] + e[z[j]])*(l[i, j] + m[i, j]), {j, 1, n}]
```

I'm trying to replace e[c[3]] by c[3] and have attempted

```
s[i, n] /. e[c[3]] -> c[3]
FullSimplify[s[i, n], c[3] == e[c[3]]]
Eliminate[{f == s[i, n], c[3] == e[c[3]]}, e[c[3]]]
Unevaluated[s[i, n]] /. e[c[3]] :>  c[3]
Unevaluated[s[i, n]] /. HoldPattern[e[c[3]]] :> c[3]
```

But none produced the intended result. I think they all failed because the term e[c[3]] does not appear *explicitly* in the expression. How can we perform substitutions when that is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[rule]
rule = e[c[j_]] :> Boole[j == 3] c[j] + Boole[j != 3] e[c[j]];

s[i, n] /. rule
```

[image]

```
s[2, 4] /. rule
```

> ```
> (e[c[1]] + e[z[1]]) (l[2, 1] + m[2, 1]) +
>  (e[c[2]] + e[z[2]]) (l[2, 2] + m[2, 2]) +
>  (c[3] + e[z[3]]) (l[2, 3] +   m[2, 3]) + 
>  (e[c[4]] + e[z[4]]) (l[2, 4] + m[2, 4])
> ```